# Copy part of a binary file between 2 file positions into new file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, binary, copy

I have a binary file with some rubbish at the start of it. I'm using MATLAB to find the start of the good stuff and want to copy the rest of the file from for example position 1388 to the end into a new file. I know I can easily read the file hexadecimal by hexadecimal into a new file, but I'm looping through a lot of big files and I'm gonna be doing this often, so I was hoping someone knows some way of dumping parts of files into new files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fidin = fopen('input.txt','r');
fseek(fidin, 1388, 'bof');
bulksize = 8192;
count = bulksize;
fid = fopen('output.txt', 'a');
while (count >= bulksize) do
    [A count] = fread(fidin, bulksize, '*uint8');
    fwrite(fid, A);
end_while
fclose(fidin);
fclose(fid);
```

input.txt input file 
Output.txt Output file
1388 offset from begin of file.

for bigger files fine tune bulksize

Comment: With "big" files this will become very inefficient- since the full file-content will have to be read into `A`.

Comment: Be specific about data types, or MATLAB will end up converting every byte to a double, then back again on writing.  `fread(fidin, bulksize, '*uint8');`

Comment: @Peter That'll be really important. changing according to Peter.

Answer (score 1):

I think amald has the right idea (+1), but my experience tells me that his implementation will undoubtedly get you hurt "when reality strikes" :)

Here's a (IMO) better way to do it:

```
function yourFcn

    % File names
    inputFile  = 'input.bin';
    outputFile = 'output.bin';

    % The computed offset (ideally, this is also done inside a try/catch)
    offset = 1388;

    % Amount of bytes per read
    N  = 8192; 



    % Open the files
    fin = fopen(inputFile, 'r');
    assert(fin > 0, 'yourFcn:ioError',...
        'Error opening input file.');

    fout = fopen(outputFile, 'w+');
    if fout < 0        
        ME = MException('yourFcn:ioError',...
            'Error opening output file.');        
        throw( closeFile(fin, inputFile, ME) );         
    end


    % Set file pointer to computed offset
    try
        fseek(fin, offset, 'bof');
    catch ME
        ME = addCause(ME, MException('yourFcn:seekFailure',...
            'Error applying offset to input file'));        
        closeBoth(ME);        
    end

    % Read N bytes at a time, and dump them in the new file
    try
        while ~feof(fin)
            assert(fwrite(fout,fread(fin,N)) == N, 'yourFcn:ioError',...
                'Mismatch between bytes read and bytes written.');
        end

    catch ME
        ME = addCause(ME, MException('yourFcn:writeError',...
            'Error writing to output file'));
        closeBoth(ME);        
    end

    closeBoth();


    % Safely close one of the files
    function ME = closeFile(fid, fileName, ME)
        try
            fclose(fid);
        catch ME2
            errMsg = sprintf(['Error closing file ''%s''; ',...
                'all file handles have been forcibly closed.'], fileName);
            if isempty(ME_in)
                ME = MException('yourFcn:closeError', errMsg);
            else
                ME.message = char(ME.message, errMsg);
            end

            ME = addCause(ME2, ME);
            fclose('all');

        end        
    end

    % Safely close both files
    function ME = closeBoth(ME_in) 
        if nargin == 0
            ME_in = []; end            
        ME = closeFile(fin, inputFile, ME_in);
        if isequal(ME,ME_in)
            ME = closeFile(fout, outputFile, ME); end 
        if ~isempty(ME)
            throw(ME); end
    end

end
```

Comment: Yeah. But my concept is first understand(So any one can use the concept again). Then error handling. For actual implementation this is a very good one.