# Java RandomAccessFile setLength but for the start of binary file

Tags: java, file-io, binary, randomaccessfile

I've been reading on RandomAccessFile and understand that its possible to truncate the end of a file by setLength to a length shorter than the file. Im trying to copy just the "end" of the file to a new file and truncate the beginning.

So for example: I want to delete the first 1300 bytes of a file and copy the rest of the file into a new file.

Is there any way of doing this?

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy part of a binary file between 2 file positions into new file in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184441/copy-part-of-a-binary-file-between-2-file-positions-into-new-file-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the RandomAccessFile seek method to seek to 1300 bytes, and then read the remainder of the file starting at the offset and use another RandomAccessFile (or different stream output) to create a new file with the values you read in from the original file beginning at the 1300 byte offset you specified?

Comment: +1 but this isn't Jeopardy, and the answer doesn't have to be in the form of a question ;-)